# What is wrong with this query? (Unknown error parsing query)

Tags: soql, query, parsing

When I run the following query in query editor I get this error.

**Error**

> Unknown error parsing query

**Query**

```
SELECT Id, OwnerId,Account.OwnerId
FROM Contact where OwnerId = Account.OwnerId limit 100
```

Does anybody know what the problem is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You can't compare a field to another field in `SOQL`.**

Salesforce has added a clear Knowledge Article to make that clear. From [Field to field comparison in an SOQL WHERE clause](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000331053&type=1&mode=1):

> Salesforce does not allow direct field to field comparison in SOQL query.

> To achieve this you can create a formula field that will compare fields and return a value (such as true or false) which you can use in a WHERE clause.

---

Originally I also pointed to the documentation on [fieldExpression Syntax](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_fieldexpression.htm) (emphasis mine):

> ```
> fieldName comparisonOperator value
> ```
>
> value: A value used to compare with the value in fieldName. You must supply a value whose data type matches the field type of the specified field. You must supply a native value—**other field names or calculations are not permitted**. If quotes are required (for example, they are not for dates and numbers), use single quotes. Double quotes result in an error.

A common workaround is to create a checkbox formula to the same effect. Then just check if it's true in your query.

Comment: Also now this is documented: [Field to field comparison in an SOQL WHERE clause](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000331053&type=1&mode=1)

Comment: Nice! Thanks @Raul for the heads up. Hopefully the documentation links are more stable now.