# What is wrong with this SOQL?

Tags: soql

What is wrong with this SOQL ?

1. `SELECT Id, Name, Sales_Group_Code__c FROM Sales_Group__c WHERE Sales_Group_Code__c = Name`
2. `SELECT Id, Name, Sales_Group_Code__c FROM Sales_Group__c WHERE Sales_Group_Code__c != Name`

This gives results :

```
SELECT Id, Name, Sales_Group_Code__c FROM Sales_Group__c
```

Comment: Do both 1st and 2nd queries are giving same results as you are getting from the last query?

Comment: In SF developer console the query 1 & 2 are not valid : "Unknown error parsing query"  you can't have a where condition based on field comparaison in SOQL I think...

Comment: I am getting "Unknown error parsing query" when running queries 1,2. Is there a workaround to get this query result in developer console ? Will queries 1,2 work in workbench ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/137265/2995. Note that you can just write a checkbox formula to do the comparison, then filter on that instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOQL is a subset of SQL

In the where clause you can only have a fieldName compared to a static value

Please refer to the SOQL documentation [fieldExpression Syntax](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_fieldexpression.htm)

> The field expression syntax of the WHERE clause in a SOQL query consists of a field name, a comparison operator, and a value that’s used to compare with the value in the field name.
>   fieldExpression uses the following syntax:
>
> fieldName comparisonOperator value

Answer (score 0):

You could add a formula field on the object to mark whether the name and sales code are the same, and then base your query on that.

Otherwise I don't think you can filter in a where clause the way you are trying to do it.